# Adding Multiple Columns in Single groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Dataset image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVwsI.png)

Please help, I have a dataset in which I have columns Country, Gas and Year from 2019 to 1991. Also attaching the snapshot of the dataset. I want to answer a question that I want to add all the values of a country column wise? For example, for Afghanistan, value should come 56.4 under 2019 (adding 28.79 + 6.23 + 16.37 + 5.01 = 56.4). Now I want it should calculate the result for every year. I have used below code for achieving 2019 data.

```
df.groupby(by='Country')['2019'].sum()
```

This is the output of that code:

```
Country
---------------------
Afghanistan     56.40
Albania         17.31
Algeria        558.67
Andorra          1.18
Angola         256.10
                ...  
Venezuela      588.72
Vietnam        868.40
Yemen           50.05
Zambia         182.08
Zimbabwe       235.06
```

I have group the data country wise and adding the 2019 column values, but how should I add values of other years in single line of code?

Please help.

I can do the code shown here, to add rows and show multiple columns like this but this will be tedious task to do so write each column name.

```
df.groupby(by='Country')[['2019','2018','2017']].sum()
```

Comment: I have also attached the image of the dataset. please have a look.

Comment: @check my solution should work for your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the column, it will sum all the numeric column.

```py
df.groupby(by='Country').sum() 

                 2019   2020   ...
Country
Afghanistan     56.40   32.4   ...
Albania         17.31   12.5   ...
Algeria        558.67  241.5   ...
Andorra          1.18    1.5   ...
Angola         256.10   32.1   ...
                ...      ...   ...
Venezuela      588.72  247.3   ...
Vietnam        868.40  323.5   ...
Yemen           50.05   55.7   ...
Zambia         182.08   23.4   ...
Zimbabwe       235.06  199.4   ...
```

Do a `reset_index()` to flatten the columns

```py
df.groupby(by='Country').sum().reset_index()

Country          2020   2019   ...
Afghanistan     56.40   32.4   ...
Albania         17.31   12.5   ...
Algeria        558.67  241.5   ...
Andorra          1.18    1.5   ...
Angola         256.10   32.1   ...
                ...      ...   ...
Venezuela      588.72  247.3   ...
Vietnam        868.40  323.5   ...
Yemen           50.05   55.7   ...
Zambia         182.08   23.4   ...
Zimbabwe       235.06  199.4   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select columns keys in your dataframe starting from column `2019` till the last column key in this way:

```
df.groupby(by='Country')[df.keys()[2:]].sum()
```

Method `df.keys` will return all dataframe columns keys in a list then you can slice it from the index of `2019` key which is `2` till end of columns keys.

Suppose you want to select columns from `2016` till `1992` column:

```
df.groupby(by='Country')[df.keys()[5:-1]].sum()
```

you just need to slice the list of columns keys in correct index order.